# is the array stored in disk too or it is just in ram?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new in programming and computer science.

- When I have an array, is it just in RAM or it has to be in the disk
  too?  for example I have:

  `int array[100];`

Is it only in RAM? If it is in the disk too, how can I implement it to be just in RAM?

- If something is in the disk it isn't implemented as an array? Is this definitely a file?

Comment: It is only on disk if the program opens a disk file and writes it there. But a *description* of your array is already on disk, in the executable file.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks, I haven't opened a file, I'v just created an array, is this array in ram or it is also in disk too?

Comment: **It is only on disk if you open a disk file and write it there.** Or if the system swaps memory to disk ;)

Comment: The C standard does not mention using RAM. You can also use paper, pen and eraser.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for your help

Comment: @WeatherVane: Actually there is no description of the array in the executable (if we ignore debug information) in C. That would imply something like RTTI, which is not available in C. The semantics are just executed by the code.

Comment: @Olaf don't be boring. Without some kind of description (I used the term loosely) in the executable there can be no array.

Comment: No offence, but these are very basic questions. I'd strongly recommend to read a book about the basics of computers and programming in general and C in detail. Asking a single question here and reading an answer will not give you the context required to really understand these basics.

Comment: @WeatherVane: There can be very well. It is **possibly** just some address and memory reserved, but there is no information it is an array, which type, etc. For a local variable (which the question leaves open), it is not even that information available. I'm very confident you know what I mean.

Comment: @Olaf your right, I would definitely try more to learn them ;)

Comment: @Olaf *For a local variable* - the description is inherent in the instructions to reserve space on the stack. Instructions to *index* an array do not make an array.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I would not call the "information in the executable", but I'll leave it at that, as it lead nowhere. (Just note that with similar argumentation, one could say the array can be very well on disk, e.g. when swapped out or after suspend-to-disc. And, yes, I really might be a bit bored right now. Sorry having bothered you;-)

Comment: @Olaf I was only trying to qualify a basic question with a simple comment, and yes, I mentioned disk swapping, but I'll let you have the last word ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have an array

```
int array[100];
```

It is only residing in the RAM, the physical memory of the system.

It can be in the disk if you take the array, and write it in some file.

---

If something is in the disk, it can be read, and then stored it in some array. Then at that point of time, it would be in RAM.

If you make some changes in the array, only the copy in the RAM will change. To make the change reflect in the disk, you have to write it back.

Answer (score 2):

The answer can get a bit complicated.

If you're working on a modern, multitasking operating system, then you are almost certainly using a *[virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)* system.  Under such a system your code operates in a continuous *virtual address space*, which will be mapped onto physical RAM as necessary.  This virtual address space is broken up into pages, and individual pages are swapped from RAM to disk and back again depending on the needs of the program that's currently running. This is how you can have multiple programs all running at the same time and not worry about them stepping on each other's data.  It also allows a program to operate as though it has an entire 32- or 64-bit address space available, even if you only have a fraction of that in physical RAM.

This swapping activity happens behind the scenes and is transparent to you; you don't have to account for it in your code.  I usually refer to that virtual address space as "storage" or "memory", reserving RAM to refer to the physical memory hardware.

If you're working on a system that doesn't use virtual memory, then obviously everything lives in RAM; there's no swapping between physical memory and disk (at least, not on the operating system's part; if necessary, you could do your own swapping).  In this case "storage", "memory", and "RAM" all mean the same thing.

With that all out of the way, your array only lives in memory; once your program exits, that array ceases to exist.  You can save the *contents* of the array to a disk file, but that's not the same thing as the array itself living on disk.